# how to use gson 2.0 on - onResponse from Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

i'm doing an http call using the new retrofit 2.0, 
and getting a callback,
i want to use gson 2.0 library to parse that json obj and to be able to do

```
jsonData.sector[2].sectorOne
```

this is my callback:

```
retrofitApi.Factory.getInstance().getCallData().enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                try {

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("myLogs", "failed to Retrive Data");
                Log.d("myLogs", "becouse: "+t);
                largeTextVar.setText("failed: " + t);
            }
        });
```

this is how my callback will look like

```
{
  "data": {
    "sector": [
      [
        {
          "scanned": false,
          "sectorOne": "",
          "sectorTwo": "",
          "sectorThree": ""
        },
        {
          "scanned": false,
          "sectorOne": "",
          "sectorTwo": "",
          "sectorThree": ""
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "curserLocation": {
    "elevation": 30,
    "horizontal": 105
  }
}
```

i'm using :

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
```

i looked everywhere on how to do this, but i couldn't find a simple solution for this, 
what is the simplest, easiest way to achieve this ?

Comment: Retrofit with the Gson converter doesn't give you JSON back, it gives you a Java object, so there is no need to use a JSON path like you've asked

Comment: how do you parse that object ? (let's say in my example) @cricket_007

Comment: @cricket_007 ? do you know how to parse the response ? it's something like response.body.string ? something like that ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to turn anything into a string. I don't know how you set up retrofit to handle things, but perhaps this will help  https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Comment: yea i'll look into it, i just wanted to acess one of the variables like do response.body.string[2].. etc...

Comment: That syntax isn't correct unless you only want the third character of the response... You have to use Gson to convert the string to a JSON object, from which you can obtain the information. However, since you are using Retrofit to obtain your data, you shouldn't need to do that (as explained below, you have a POJO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey i will explain how to convert `JSON` response to `POJO` :

First of all you must create a POJO class in : [JSON Schema 2 POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

1. Paste your example `JSON` response
2. Select Source Type : JSON
3. annotation style  : Gson

It will generate a `POJO` class for you.

Then in your `onResponse` method :

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if(response.code()==200){
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                YourPOJOClass yourpojo=new YourPOJOClass ();
                try {
                    yourpojo= gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(),YourPOJOClass.class); 
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // handle failure to read error
                    Log.v("gson error","error when gson process");  
                }
        }
```

Dont forget to add `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'`

> Another way to do this : create a pojo class like in above.

In your API :

```
@POST("endpoint")
public Call<YourPOJOClass> exampleRequest();
```

When calling this :

```
    OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .create();

    Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(okClient)
            .build();

    YourApiClass service = client.create(YourApiClass.class);

    Call<YourPOJOClass> call=service.exampleRequest();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<YourPOJOClass>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<YourPOJOClass> call, Response<YourPOJOClass> response) {
            //already Gson convertor factory converted your response body to pojo
            response.body().getCurserLocation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<YourPOJOClass> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: is there a way you know to acess directly the vars on the response i get from the function ?

Comment: no i dont know , i am using pojo classes to get variables. The proper way i know .

Comment: jsonschema2pojo creates 4 files in the zip folder, in your example you used, YourPOJOClass yourpojo=new YourPOJOClass (), which class from POJO did you mean ? can you exaplain the answer a little bit more ?

Comment: look this photo , look blue lines in photo . Type your classname its just example you can give it a specific name : http://hizliresim.com/RkW8lR .If it generates multi classes add all classes to your project.