# How to post array in retrofit android

Tags: android, retrofit

How can I post following parameter in retrofit through post method ?

```
 "params":{"body": {
    "learning_objective_uuids": [
      "ED4FE2BB2008FDA9C8133FF462959C0968FAB98C4D1DB8F2"
    ],
    "note": "FasfAFSASFASDF",
    "user_uuids": [
      "EDF8B7EC20005ACC5C40FF7D6E988801F5BAD83CBBCDB97F",
      "EDF8F78F2000569C64101F244AA20C0070D2A7FCB1939E19"
    ]
  }
}
} }
```

Comment: which parameter? There are many parameters more than one...

Comment: These parameters :- "learning_objective_uuids": [
  "ED4FE2BB2008FDA9C8133FF462959C0968FAB98C4D1DB8F2"
],
"note": "FasfAFSASFASDF",
"user_uuids": [
  "EDF8B7EC20005ACC5C40FF7D6E988801F5BAD83CBBCDB97F",
  "EDF8F78F2000569C64101F244AA20C0070D2A7FCB1939E19"
]
} } }

Comment: I wrote answer below..

Comment: please type any reason in comments when you going downvote. This is constructive way i think

Comment: @Revenge , I don't know why some stupid persons down vote the question. Its a genuine question . what do you think ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("service_name") 
   void functionName(
        @FieldMap Map<String, String> learning_objective_uuids, @FieldMap Map<String, String> user_uuids, @Field("note") String note,
        Callback<CallBackClass> callback
    );
```

**Better solution :** Use arraylist.. Reference link : [johnsonsu](http://johnsonsu.com/android-retrofit-posting-array/)

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("service_name") 
       void functionName(
            @Field("learning_objective_uuids[]") ArrayList<String> learning_objective_uuids, @Field("user_uuids[]") ArrayList<String> user_uuids, @Field("note") String note,
            Callback<CallBackClass> callback
        );
```

Comment: Getting the following response :-
retrofit.RetrofitError: 400 Bad Request

Comment: Put your function that you wrote yourself.

Comment: Sure brother, Can you please tell me what is "lost_project_reasons[]"  ?

Comment: thanks for the answer, Second solution with arrayList worked! +1

Comment: you can also send array as int[] or long[] like this : @Field("lost_project_reasons[]") int[] learning_objective_uuids

Comment: is that Retrofit 1.x or 2.x? or both?

Comment: @hkaraoglu your answer works well. but if i try same with hashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> then response is something like ["[value-1,value-1]"]. can you help me out what i can do if i want to send parameter key name at runtime. also number of keys are not fixed. so i have to use HashMap only. please help.

Comment: The best solution! Thanks!

Comment: A working solution for php servers which gets an array as a post param.
In my case, the conjuction of @Field("fieldName[]") SomeObject[] param) worked.

Answer (score 8):

see this example where i need to pass registration fields data as json request

```
@POST("magento2apidemo/rest/V1/customers")
Call<RegisterEntity> customerRegistration(@Body JsonObject registrationData);
```

here i have created registrationData is

```
private static JsonObject generateRegistrationRequest() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            JSONObject subJsonObject = new JSONObject();
            subJsonObject.put("email", "abc@xyz.com");
            subJsonObject.put("firstname", "abc");
            subJsonObject.put("lastname", "xyz");

            jsonObject.put("customer", subJsonObject);
            jsonObject.put("password", "password");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject gsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonObject.toString());
        return gsonObject;
    }
```

Comment: Only point to be noted is 
"when you want to send array to server add that values to JsonArray and put it inside JsonObject."

Answer (score 7):

As of today, running the Retrofit `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'`

This works perfectly...

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("index.php?action=item")
Call<Reply> updateManyItem(@Header("Authorization") String auth_token, @Field("items[]") List<Integer> items, @Field("method") String method);
```

You can disregard the `@Header` and `@Field("method")` .... the main piece is `@Field("items[]") List<Integer> items`

This is what allows you to send the items.  On the API side I am simply looking for an array of integers and this works perfectly.

Comment: The only thing I forgot was the "[]" after the name of the field. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Go to this site : [JSON Schema 2 POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Paste your example Json format and then

Select source type : JSON , annotation style : None

Create a POJO class then , for example your class name : MyPOJOClass

Then in your Api :

```
@POST("endpoint")
public Call<Void> postArray(@Body MyPOJOClass mypojoclass);
```

If you have headers too you can add them in parameters like that :

```
@Header("Accept") String accept,@Header("Content-Type") String contentType
```

@Edit : for your comment checkout my answer : [how-to-use-gson-2-0-on-onresponse-from-retrofit-2-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098347/how-to-use-gson-2-0-on-onresponse-from-retrofit-2-0/37099604#37099604)

Comment: Currently I am using this method:-  @POST(Constants.POST_UPLOAD_NOTES)
    public void postNotes(@Body JSONArray jsonArray ,@Query("note") String note, Callback<NotesResponse> callback);

}

Comment: checkout my @Edit section, you can find an example request and how to handle response .You can combine both answers

Answer (score 1):

I've found a new workaround:

you can send it as a String:

```
@POST("CollectionPoints")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<SomeResponse> postSomething(@Field("ids")String ids);
```

and send pass it like this:

```
Call<SomeResponse> call = service.postSomething("0","0", Arrays.toString(new int[]{53551, 53554}));
```

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) is the Best solution for JSON Object/Array related problems.

Here, I am sharing my easiest solution for passing array type value in retrofit API

```
id: ArrayList<String> //Already initilized 
status: String  //Already initilized 

val jsonObject = JsonObject()
val toJson = Gson().toJsonTree(id) //Only one line to covert array JsonElement

jsonObject.add("id", toJson) //Add Json Element in JsonObject

jsonObject.addProperty("status", status)
```

API Calling using **jsonObject**

```
@POST("API_END_POINT")
fun changeStatusOfList(@Body jsonObject: JsonObject): Observable<Response<RETURN_TYPE>>
```

Output in Log:

```
{"id":["426","427"],"status":"1"}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to send a list of the same name the only thing that worked for me in retrofit2 is to use `@Query`

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("service_name") 
   void functionName(
        @Query("category") List<Int> categories
    );
```

this will send it like: `https://example.com/things?category=100&category=101&category=105`

the accepted answers seem not to work in Retrofit2