# How to send Arrays / Lists with Retrofit

Tags: android, http-post, retrofit

I need to send a list / an array of Integer values with Retrofit to the server (via POST)
I do it this way:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/profile/searchProfile")
Call<ResponseBody> postSearchProfile(
        @Field("age") List<Integer> age
};
```

and send it like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> ages = new ArrayList<>();
        ages.add(20);
        ages.add(30);

ISearchProfilePost iSearchProfile = gsonServerAPIRetrofit.create(ISearchProfilePost.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = iSearchProfile.postSearchProfile(
                ages
        );
```

The problem is, the values reach the server not comma separated. So the values there are like **age: 2030** instead of **age: 20, 30**.

I was reading (e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37254442/1565635) that some had success by writing the parameter with [] like an array but that leads only to parameters called **age[] : 2030**.
I also tried using Arrays as well as Lists with Strings. Same problem. Everything comes directly in one entry.

So what can I do?

Comment: Check that solution as well, I am following Gson to solve a similar problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64621637/12228284

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To send as an Object

This is your ISearchProfilePost.class

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/profile/searchProfile")
Call<ResponseBody> postSearchProfile(@Body ArrayListAge ages);
```

Here you will enter the post data in pojo class

```
public class ArrayListAge{
    @SerializedName("age")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<String> ages;
    public ArrayListAge(ArrayList<String> ages) {
        this.ages=ages;
    }
}
```

Your retrofit call class

```
ArrayList<Integer> ages = new ArrayList<>();
        ages.add(20);
        ages.add(30);

ArrayListAge arrayListAge = new ArrayListAge(ages);
ISearchProfilePost iSearchProfile = gsonServerAPIRetrofit.create(ISearchProfilePost.class);
Call<ResponseBody> call = iSearchProfile.postSearchProfile(arrayListAge);
```

To send as an Array List check this link https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1064

You forget to add `age[]`

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/profile/searchProfile")
Call<ResponseBody> postSearchProfile(
    @Field("age[]") List<Integer> age
};
```

Comment: Well, but this sends my object as the body but not as one "Array" among other fields. Or isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Retrofit can do this now at least I tested with this -> `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'`

For example

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("index.php?action=item")
Call<Reply> updateStartManyItem(@Header("Authorization") String auth_token, @Field("items[]") List<Integer> items, @Field("method") String method);
```

This is the piece we are looking at.

```
@Field("items[]") List<Integer> items
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using "now" version 2.1 when 2.6 is already out? Or is that supposed to mean "from 2.1 on this works"?

Comment: Just what I tested it on...edited the answer to include this detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload array of object using Retrofit then follow the steps. It will work 100%.
In my case I have 2 params one is userId and second is location_data. In second params I have to pass array of objects.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/send_array_data")
Call<StartResponseModal> postData(@Field("user_id") String user_id,
                                             @Field("location_data") String 
jsonObject);
```

then in your MainActivity.class / Fragments.

```
 ArrayList<JSONObject> obj_arr;  // define this at top level.
 try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                obj_arr = new ArrayList<>();
                 // LocationData is model class. 
                for (LocationData cart : arrayList) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.put("latitude", cart.getLatitude());
                    jsonObject.put("longitude", cart.getLongitude());
                    jsonObject.put("address", cart.getAddress());
                    jsonObject.put("battery", cart.getBattery());
                    jsonObject.put("is_gps_on", cart.getIs_gps_on());
                    jsonObject.put("is_internet_on", 
                     cart.getIs_internet_on());
                    jsonObject.put("type", cart.getType());
                    jsonObject.put("date_time", cart.getDate_time());
                    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
                    obj_arr.add(jsonObject);
                }
                Log.e("JSONArray", String.valueOf(jsonArray));
            } catch (JSONException jse) {
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }




 String user_id = SharedPreferenceUtils.getString(getActivity(), 
 Const.USER_ID);
    RetrofitAPI retrofitAPI = 
 APIClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitAPI.class);
    Call<StartResponseModal> call = 
 retrofitAPI.postData(user_id,obj_arr.toString());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<StartResponseModal>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<StartResponseModal> call, 
  Response<StartResponseModal> response) {
            // Handle success
            if (response.isSuccessful() && 
  response.body().getErrorCode().equals("0")) {
                // Process the response here
                Log.e("Hello Room data send","Success");
                deleteItemsFromDatabase();


            } else {
                // Handle API error
                Log.e("Hello Room data send","failed else");

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<StartResponseModal> call, Throwable t) {
            // Handle failure
            Log.e("Hello Room send","failure");

        }
    });
```