# Android Retrofit - Pass list of objects as associative array

Tags: android, retrofit

I have an API which expects a list of exercises as input:

```
exercises[0][duration]=10
exercises[0][type]=jump
exercises[1][duration]=20
exercises[1][type]=roll
```

On Android side, I have my API class built using Retrofit.

How do I pass my `List<Exercise>` to the API method in order to get the above parameters.

Currently tried:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/v1/patient/{id}/workout")
fun addPatientWorkout(@Path("id") id: Long,
                      @Field("title") title: String,
                      @Field("exercises[]") exercises: List<Map<String,String>>)
        : Single<Response<Workout>>
```

But that does not give what I expect. Instead:

`exercises[]={duration:10, type=jump}&exercises[]={duration:20, type=roll}`

Comment: I would pass a simple "exercises" List in JSON format, not as a Map. Once you retrieve it as a JSON, this format looks simple to process to array: "exercises":[{"duration"...},{...}]

Comment: I have no control on the API. I must use that format.

Comment: please check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698715/how-to-send-arrays-lists-with-retrofit

Comment: Got it. Was @FieldMap (see own answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for is the `@FieldMap` annotation. That allows to build a map of name/values to pass as POST parameters.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/v1/patient/{id}/workout")
fun addPatientWorkout(@Path("id") id: Long,
                      @Field("title") title: String,
                      @FieldMap exercises: Map<String,String>)
        : Single<Response<Workout>>
```

And that gets called with the following code:

```
    val exerciseFields: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
    workout.exercises.forEachIndexed { index, exercise ->
        exerciseFields["exercises[$index][duration]"] = exercise.duration.toString()
        exerciseFields["exercises[$index][type]"] =exercise.type.name.toLowerCase()
    }

    return addPatientWorkout(
            workout.patient?.id ?: -1,
            workout.title,
            exerciseFields)
```

Comment: Ohh it exists!, I just posted primitive way to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Format it and post as a `String` instead of `List<Map<String,String>>` because retrofit always converts maps into json.

You can convert it as follows :

```
        Exercise[] exercises = new Exercise[2];
        exercises[0] = new Exercise(10, "jump");
        exercises[1] = new Exercise(20, "roll");

        String postString = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < exercises.length; i++) {

            Exercise ex = exercises[i];
            postString += "exercises[" + i +"][duration]=" + ex.duration + "\n";
            postString += "exercises[" + i +"][type]=" + ex.type + "\n";
        }

        System.out.println(postString);
```

Exercise class :

```
    class Exercise {

        public Exercise(int duration, String type) {

            this.duration = duration;
            this.type = type;
        }

        int duration;
        String type;
    }
```

Your API function will look like this :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/v1/patient/{id}/workout")
fun addPatientWorkout(@Path("id") id: Long,
                      @Field("title") title: String,
                      @Field("exercises"): exercises, String)
        : Single<Response<Workout>>
```