# Send an array of strings to a server from Android using Retrofit

Tags: java, php, android, json, retrofit

I want to send an array of strings to the server from an Android app using Retrofit. I have no idea how can I send it and receive it in server side:

```
//api interface...

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("sendArray.php")
Call<ResponseModel> sendAns(@Field("ans[]") String[] ans);

//sending array in main activity

String[] ans = {"ans1","ans2","ans3"};
Call<ResponseModel> call = apiObject.sendAns(ans);
call.en....

//server side php code to get array

$ans = $_POST['ans[]'];
$ans1 = $ans[1];
```

I expected the value of $ans1 = "ans2" but we got nothing.

Comment: Why don't you `var_dump($_POST)` to see how's your value looks like, then you know how to access it.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698715/how-to-send-arrays-lists-with-retrofit

Comment: can you show me the code for var_dump($_POST)

Answer (score 0):

send and receive array like this:

```
  @POST("sendArray.php")
  Call<ResponseModel> getSomething(@Body String[] ans );
```

And if you want to name your array then create `RequestModel` with array inside named as you want. Also you can set name using `@SerializedName` annotation

```
public class YourBodyRequest {
    @SerializedName("ans[]")
    public String[] ans;
}
```

And:

```
 @POST("sendArray.php")
 Call<ResponseModel> request(@Body YourBodyRequest request );
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. can you post php code to recieve?

Comment: At this time,java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.asus.simple.ResponseModel.getResponse()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.asus.simple.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:90)

Comment: For thar please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207488/get-all-variables-sent-with-post

Comment: You getting null because there is no response, also with network and response I would suggest always check for null before doing anything

Comment: <?php 
require "init.php";

   $jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');   
   $jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString,true);

   $a = $jsonArray[1];

$qry = "INSERT INTO `answer_table`(`ans`, `ques_id`, `test_code`) VALUES ('$b','12','XYZ')";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);

if($result){
 $status = "ok";
 echo json_encode(array("response"=>$status));
}else{
 $status = "error";
 echo json_encode(array("response"=>$status));
 
}

?>

Comment: it's giving response ok. and I am unable to fix it.

Comment: use var_dump($_POST) and follow your Post response