# Passing lots parameters including arrays in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I need to send this request to my API

```
?name=yourname&address=youraddress&phone=1245689&email=me@mail.com&gender=M&birth_date=01011998&birth_place=Surabaya&job=myjob .. other 7 string parameters .. &skills[]=skill1&skills[]=skill2
```

I could do it like this [How to post array in retrofit android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254232/how-to-post-array-in-retrofit-android)

But, is there a simple way to do it in retrofit using @Body rather than @Field/@FieldMap?

Comment: It is available in the link you have shared, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37254341/3134215) answer

Comment: @RaviRupareliya wow, i dont realize it. i'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254232/how-to-post-array-in-retrofit-android/37254341#37254341), but if you are to lazy and has made tons of code and don't want to rewrite them, just use `List<Object> myObject = new ArrayList<Object>();` (using my own code as example) :

```
class UserFormRequest {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    ...
    private List<SkillObject> skills = new ArrayList<SkillObject>(); // this

}
```