# Retrofit2 Sending Array as HashMap results in a different format

Tags: java, arrays, retrofit2

I am trying to send a `String[]` array as a name value pair in a HashMap to the backend but the backend receives the payload as follows:

```
Parameters: {"gallery_file_ids"=>"[Ljava.lang.String;@4acac2e"}
```

The array values are not sent and also an additional "" is surrounding the array value. Here's my code:

**Setting up the array:**

```
String[] gallery_array = new String[2];
gallery_array[0] = "2134564";

HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("gallery_file_ids", gallery_array);
```

**Retrofit API**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PATCH("api/profile.json")
Call<Profile> updateProfile(@FieldMap HashMap<String, Object> params);
```

From what I understand, a string representation of the string array is bring formed by retrofit. How can I resolve this?

Comment: `gallery_array` is just a reference to the memory address that contains the contents of the array. You have to say what you want to do with the array (i.e. turn it into a comma separated list). Maybe for Retrofit it is enough to declare the `HashMap` as `<String, String[]>`

Comment: @nbokmans No difference mate. Still the same response is logged in backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it by creating a custom java class containing an ArrayList instead of a string array:

**Custom class - NewGalleryUpload.java**

```
public class NewGalleryUpload {
    public ArrayList<String> gallery_file_ids = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**The Retrofit API was changed to the following:**

```
//An object is sent in the body instead of a HashMap
@PATCH("api/profile.json")
Call<BusinessProfile> updateProfile(@Body NewGalleryUpload newGalleryUpload);
```

So basically, a new object of `NewGalleryUpload` is initialised and the values are added to the `gallery_file_ids` ArrayList and passed in the body of the request. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

`@FieldMap` accept real type is `Map<String, String>`, whatever your values is `String[]` or other, values are converted to strings using `String.valueOf(Object)`, it is the same as [@Field](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Field.html).

if you want to use arrays as params, you can try following code:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PATCH("api/profile.json")
Call<Profile> updateProfile(@Field("gallery_file_ids")  ArrayList<String> ids);
```

or you can see the question [How to post array in retrofit android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254232/how-to-post-array-in-retrofit-android)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add values in Hashmap<> then you have to enter one index value at a time like this: params.put("gallery_file_ids", gallery_array[0]);

Answer (score 0):

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("api/profile.json")
Call<Profile> updateProfile(@body List<YuorClassName> data);
```

You need to pass your class type list to post jsonArrayList.

and to use custom with custom header it will be like this -

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("api/profile.json")
Call<Profile> updateProfile(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers, @body List<YuorClassName> data);
```

and from your activity -

```
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("SESSION_ID",getSeassionDataNew().getData().getSESSIONID());
    headers.put("SESSION_TOKEN", getSeassionDataNew().getData().getSESSIONTOKEN());

    .....

    List<YuorClassName> data = new ArrayList<>();

    ......

    Call call = apiInterface.updateProfile(headers , data);
```