# how to send this JSON Array from android to server using retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I want to send this parameter in request and tried to send a simple array list but that was not working

```
"Language": [
    "string","string","string"
  ]
```

Comment: Which annotation you have used for this API?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254232/how-to-post-array-in-retrofit-android

Answer (score 2):

If "Language" is key and ["string1","string2","string3"] is value then create method in interface as below.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(LINK_API)
Call<ResponseModel> getResponse(@Field("Language") String languageArray);
```

and call it using interface instance like this :

```
JSONArray languageArray = new JSONArray();
languageArray.add("string1");
languageArray.add("string2");
languageArray.add("string3");

String langArray = languageArray.toString();

Call<ResponseModel> responseModel = apiObject.getResponse(langArray);

responseModel.enqueue(...);
```

This will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

try post query with field parameter as string..

convert your jsonObject to String using,

```
String b = json_object.toString();
```

At Server Side, convert string back to JsonObject or whatever else you need.