# How to post an integer list using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to post an Integer list using retrofit.
It looks like this image in postman

[image]

In postman everything is good but when I want to post this using retrofit, possibilities don't post successfully.

Here is my code :

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json" , "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("locations/add")
Observable<Response<SimpleResponseJM>> addLocation(
        @Field("possibilities[]") List<Integer> possibilities);
```

Comment: `@Field("possibilities[]")` is this one of the parameters?

Comment: Yes. It is one of the parameters.

Comment: Okay, are you getting any error ?

Comment: No. But the possibilities don't insert in the server database.

Comment: Can you show the code of inserting?

Comment: No. I working on the android application and I don't have access to the inserting code. But when I want to get this with another request possibilities is empty.

Comment: Inserting code working fine because when I post using postman possibilities insert successfully.

Comment: Okay, check if you have inserted INTERNET Permission

Comment: I insert Internet Permission. This request has many fields and just possibilities is empty. Other fields don't have any problem and insert successfully.

Comment: Are you sure, you are passing data in possibilities variable from your activity?

Comment: Yes of course. I pass an Integer List that is not empty.

Comment: I'm sorry, Without looking at your code, It's difficult to tell what's wrong. May be someone else can help you with this. Have a nice day!

Comment: Instead of List try arraylist.. You can find more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37254442/4824088

Comment: Using ArrayList instead of List solve the problem. Thank you very much :)