# Retrofit 2 adds java class name when naming variable in request data

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have to send data in the following model:

```
{
"TransactionType": "testType",
"TransactionReference": "testSectionReference",
"TransactionDate": "2018-10-22T06:22:30.632Z",
"TransactionLines": [
{
  "ProductReference": "testProductReference",
  "ShipDate": "2018-10-22T06:22:30.632Z",
  "Quantity": 1,
  "AwardAmount": 2.0,
  "TotalAmount": 3.0
}
]
}
```

I do so by creating a `transactionBody`, which I send as a body in the request like this:

```
@POST("/myCustomUrlPath")
Call<Transaction> createTransaction(
        @Body TransactionBody transactionBody
        );
```

The `TransactionBody` has the following parameter:

transactionType - `String`

transactionReference - `String`

transactionDate - `String`

transactionLines - `TransactionLines //(my custom model)`

All seems good, until I test the request and see that the properties of my `TransactionLines` model are not sent like this:

`"productReference":"testProductReference"`

but instead they are sent with my java class path like this:

`"model.transactionLines.productReference":"testProductReference"`

This of course makes my server return an error, because it's expecting `productReference` and not `model.transactionLines.productReference`. How do I remove the path of my java class model before the variable name?

Edit:

I don't think my problem is anything close to what is suggested as a possible already asked question. They are asking for posting an array in json and I am having problem with posting the name of a variable in a custom object used in json post.

However, @Jeel Vankhede is right. Serializing the name of the variable removed the path of my java class and now the request is filled with correct data. Thank you!

Comment: use `@SerializedName()` property from Gson library, it'll work in your case.

Comment: please post your TransactionLines model

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37254442/5978440)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post array in retrofit android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254232/how-to-post-array-in-retrofit-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jeel suggested in the comment, you should use the `@SerializedName` annotation in your model class. This is how your model should look:

```
@SerializedName("productReference")
private String productReference;
```

In your `TransactionLines` class. When this property is not specified, it'll just use the default name for serialization, which usually works out, but if for some reason you want a different one, that's where you specify it. I use it for example when I really dislike naming my Java variable like `some_property`, and API needs it to be called like that, I'll do something like:

```
@SerializedName("some_property")
private String someProperty;
```