# Send a array in HashMap<String, String> via Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to send a post request via Retrofit in Android, but the json is being bad formatted when I put an array in the body.

```
var data = ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>()

var dataArray = HashMap<String, String>()
dataArray.put("id_motorista", user.data.id_motorista)
dataArray.put("id_veiculo", user.data.id_veiculo)
dataArray.put("data_hora", currentDate.toString())
data.add(dataArray)

var reqBody = HashMap<String, String>()
reqBody.put("action", "add_diario_bordo")
reqBody.put("data", ???)
```

The retrofit service:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("appmm/")
fun login(@Body login: Map<String, String>): Call<LoginResponse>
```

I tried to convert for Json using GSON, to send as String, Any>, but didnt work.

Comment: just pass `dataArray` to your login function

Comment: Can you share json request which worked in postman or share your postman collection.

Comment: The way you are doing will not serialize your object into right format. I would suggest you to create your json object and put the values in the same format which is required at your server and then send it in the body of your request.

Comment: i think used this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254232/how-to-post-array-in-retrofit-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommended you to send one String instead an Object (or HashMap).

By using the Gson library you can transform almost any object (read about serializable objects) into a string and then send it, of course on the other side you have to cast it to the original class format.

example:

Object to String:

```
MyUser mUser = new MyUser();
String json = new Gson().toJson(mUser);
```

String to Object:

```
 MyUser mUser = new Gson().fromJson(json, MyUser.class)
```

HashMap to String:

```
HashMap<S, T> map = new HashMap<>();
String json = new Gson().toJson(map);
```

String back to HashMap:

```
// type token == new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Playlist>>() {}
HashMap<S, T> map = null;
map = new Gson().fromJson(prefs.getString(KEY, ""), typeToken.getType());
```