# How to send array in retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

How can I post following parameter in retrofit through post method as an input parameter of a request?

```
widget:[
    {
        "id": 37,
        "fkAnagraficaId": 100,
        "name": "Fatture",
        "position": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 38,
        "fkAnagraficaId": 100,
        "name": "Ordini",
        "position": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Basically what you're looking for is called `@Body` annotation on your retrofit POST method call as annotation to method parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can very well send array directly as param like this

```
@Headers({
    "Content-type: application/json"
})
Response postWidgets(@Body List<String> widgets);
```

But if you want to send as JSON you mentioned ( with widgets as key and array as value) then you may need to write POJO having widgets as array field and use that POJO instance here

```
@Headers({
    "Content-type: application/json"
})
Response postWidgets(@Body MyPojo myPojo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit uses JSON so you can use `["something0", "somethingElse"]` you can also look at: [How to post array in retrofit android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254232/how-to-post-array-in-retrofit-android)