# How to pass array in array for retrofit for android with kotlin

Tags: kotlin

[image]

I am trying to call a API where i need to pass task name and time in array and project name and date, Also data should be pass in array. I have tried so many time but did not get desired output.
Kindly help me with this. I am attaching screen shots of postman and also JSON Viewer, So you guys can see everything and answer me properly.
Thank you guys in advance for help me

[image]

I have tried but didnt get any output

Comment: Please don't post images. Instead of this add code directly to question body

Comment: @mechnicov can you please send code or if you have any refrence than please share link..Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254232/how-to-post-array-in-retrofit-android

Kindly check this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the data class you are creating is wrong. Using the JSONTOKOTLIN plugin, give it the desired json to create it by itself

Comment: I have treid already this but it didn't worked. Actually I have tried to add all data in array list but when i send data on server Data has send with entire Class name so due to this Issue the app has been crashed I am sending you Log print so you can understand what is the problem. log print "[MyTasks(project_name=Projects, tasks=[com.example.timeleavelogs.models.tasksmodel.TasksAndTimeModal@83dec71])]"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).